# Android 3 Spinners

Tags: android

First of I'm a novice. I've been through the example of how to create a spinner, and I've searched this site and the Internet for how to create multiple spinners with the list in the 2nd spinner being dependant upon the first spinner and the 3rd spinner list being dependent upon the selection in the 2nd. However I cannot find a tutorial or solution anywhere.

Could someone provide some help to as to how this would be done (a tutorial would be great :))

Basically A list in Spinner1 could be 'Manufacturer', on selection Produces a list of 'Models' in Spinner2 and from the selection of Model in spinner2 produces a list of 'Issues' in Spinner3.

Any help would be great,

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

[See here this demo have Two Spinner and works](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-spinner-tutorial.html)

so `onItemSelected method you can check your fisrt,second,third spinner value and set as per your requires.`

Comment: Thanks for the link, however after importing it into eclipse it showed loads of errors and it seems lots of bits are missing/incomplete. Has that tutorial/download worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner1,spinner2,spinner3;

    public static final String AP_DISTRICTS = "Andhra Pradesh";
    public static final String TN_DISTRICTS = "Tamil Nadu";
    public static final String TG_DISTRICTS = "Telangana";
    public static final String VC_DISTRICTS = "Victoria";
    public static final String TS_DISTRICTS = "Tasmania";
    public static final String QL_DISTRICTS = "Queens Land";
    public static final String KR_DISTRICTS = "Karachi";
    public static final String LH_DISTRICTS = "Lahore";
    public static final String SI_DISTRICTS = "Sindh";

    public static final String SELECT_COUNTRY = "--Select Country--";
    public static final String SELECT_STATE = "--Select State--";
    public static final String SELECT_DISTRICT = "--Select District--";


    String[] country = {SELECT_COUNTRY, "India", "Australia", "Pakistan"};


    String[] indiaStates = {SELECT_STATE, AP_DISTRICTS, TN_DISTRICTS, TG_DISTRICTS};
    String[] australiaStates = {"SELECT_STATE", VC_DISTRICTS, TS_DISTRICTS, QL_DISTRICTS};
    String[] pakistanStates = {"SELECT_STATE", KR_DISTRICTS, LH_DISTRICTS, SI_DISTRICTS};

    String[] apDistricts = {SELECT_DISTRICT, "Nellore", "Chittoor", "Prakasam"};
    String[] tnDistricts = {SELECT_DISTRICT, "Chennai", "Thiruvallur", "Kanchipuram"};
    String[] tgDistricts = {SELECT_DISTRICT, "Hyderabad", "Secunderabad", "Ranga Reddy"};

    String[] vicDistricts = {SELECT_DISTRICT, "Ballarat South", "Ballarat North", "Ballarat East"};
    String[] tsDistricts = {SELECT_DISTRICT, "Tasmania East", "Tasmania West", "Tasmania South"};
    String[] qsDistricts = {SELECT_DISTRICT, "Queens Land East", "Queens Land West", "Queens Land North"};


    String[] krDistricts = {SELECT_DISTRICT, "Karachi East", "Karachi North", "Karachi South"};
    String[] lhDistricts = {SELECT_DISTRICT, "Lahore South", "Lahore East", "Lahore North"};
    String[] siDistricts = {SELECT_DISTRICT, "Sindh West", "Sindh North", "Sindh East"};







    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_item1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_item2);
        spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_item3);

        spinner1.setSelection(0);
        spinner2.setSelection(0);
        spinner3.setSelection(0);

        setSpinner(spinner1, country);
        setSpinner(spinner2, indiaStates);
        setSpinner(spinner3, apDistricts);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, country);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);


        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                switch (i){

                    case 0:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "please Select Country", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        spinner1.setSelection(0);
                        spinner2.setSelection(0);
                        spinner3.setSelection(0);

                        break;

                    case 1:
                        setSpinner(spinner2, indiaStates);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        setSpinner(spinner2, australiaStates);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        setSpinner(spinner2, pakistanStates);
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });


        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                String selectedItem = adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if (spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "please Select Country", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                     spinner2.setSelection(0);
                     spinner3.setSelection(0);
                    return;

                }
                if (i == 0){
                    spinner3.setSelection(0);
                    return;
                }



                switch (selectedItem){

                    case  AP_DISTRICTS:
                        setSpinner(spinner3, apDistricts);
                        break;

                    case TN_DISTRICTS :
                        setSpinner(spinner3, tnDistricts);
                        break;

                    case TG_DISTRICTS:
                        setSpinner(spinner3, tgDistricts);
                        break;

                    case VC_DISTRICTS:
                        setSpinner(spinner3, vicDistricts);
                        break;

                    case TS_DISTRICTS:
                        setSpinner(spinner3, tsDistricts);
                        break;

                    case QL_DISTRICTS:
                        setSpinner(spinner3, qsDistricts);
                        break;

                    case KR_DISTRICTS:
                        setSpinner(spinner3, krDistricts);
                        break;

                    case LH_DISTRICTS:
                        setSpinner(spinner3, lhDistricts);
                        break;

                    case SI_DISTRICTS :
                        setSpinner(spinner3, siDistricts);
                        break;

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });


        spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if (spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0 || spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "please Select State", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    spinner2.setSelection(0);
                    spinner3.setSelection(0);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });









    }

    private void setSpinner(Spinner spinner2, String[] states) {

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by handling `onItemSelected` event.
you can store your data in database or in arrays and on selection you can populate particular array in particular spinner.

Answer (score 0):

this is straight from one of my app's (actually the first app i ever wrote) so its not pretty but it works

```
package com.skyesmechanical.OilProductionLogApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class test extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public String spinnerPipeLengthText = "";
    public String spinnerNaturalGasText = "";
    public String spinnerPropaneGasText = "";
    public Spinner spinnerPipeLength;
    public Spinner spinnerTypeGas;
    public Spinner spinnerSupplyPressure;
    public static Integer spinnerPipeLengthInt = 0;
    public static Integer spinnerTypeGasInt = 0;
    public static Integer spinnerPropaneGasInt = 0;
    public static Integer spinnerSupplyPressureInt = 0;
    public static Integer finalRow = 0;
    public boolean supplyPressureVisible = false;
    public boolean pipeLengthVisible = false;

    static TextView textViewSize15;
    static TextView textViewSize19;
    static TextView textViewSize25;
    static TextView textViewSize31;
    static TextView textViewSize37;
    static TextView textViewSize46;
    static TextView textViewSize62;
    static TextView textViewSupplyPressure;
    static TextView textViewSelectPipeLength;

    public static Integer baseTableRowNumber = 0;   
    public static Cursor cursorResult;
    // these to int's keep a false Toast message from appearing
    private int intSpinnerCountGas = 0;
    private int intSpinnerCountSupply = 0;
    private int intSpinnerCountLength = 0;
    private static final int NO_OF_EVENTS_GAS = 1;
    private static final int NO_OF_EVENTS_SUPPLY = 1;
    private static final int NO_OF_EVENTS_LENGTH = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle state) { 
        super.onCreate(state);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //check if app just started or is being restored from memory
        if (state != null )  { 
            //app is being restored from memory, not executed from scratch
            //initialize the fields to the last used;
            supplyPressureVisible = state.getBoolean("supplyPressureVisible");
            pipeLengthVisible = state.getBoolean("pipeLengthVisible");
            spinnerTypeGasInt = state.getInt("spinnerTypeGasInt");
            spinnerSupplyPressureInt = state.getInt("spinnerSupplyPressureInt");
            spinnerPipeLengthInt = state.getInt("spinnerPipeLengthInt");
            finalRow = state.getInt("finalRow");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "savedInstanceState != null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }  //end if
        // call doInBackground
        new LoadDataBaseTask().doInBackground();        


        mainProgram ();
    } // end onCreate

    // performs database query outside GUI thread
    private class LoadDataBaseTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> {
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(CSSTPipeSizingActivity.this);
        // perform the database access
        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground (Object... params) {
            try {
                myDbHelper.createDataBase();
            } 
            catch (IOException ioe) {
                throw new Error("Unable to create database");
            }
            try {
                myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            }
            catch(SQLException sqle) {
                throw sqle;
            }
            return myDbHelper.getData(); 
        } // end method doInBackground

        // use the Cursor returned from the doInBackground method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            //myDbHelper.changeCursor(result); // set the adapter's Cursor
            myDbHelper.close();
        } // end method onPostExecute
    } // end class LoadDataBaseTask 

    public void mainProgram () {
        spinnerTypeGas = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTypeGas);
        spinnerSupplyPressure = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSupplyPressure);
        spinnerPipeLength = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerPipeLength);

        spinnerSupplyPressure.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        textViewSelectPipeLength.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        spinnerPipeLength.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if (supplyPressureVisible == true) spinnerSupplyPressure.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else spinnerSupplyPressure.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (pipeLengthVisible == true) spinnerPipeLength.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else spinnerPipeLength.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        //Sets up the spinnerTypeGas spinner
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterTypeGas = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.TypeGas, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterTypeGas.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerTypeGas.setAdapter(adapterTypeGas);

        //Sets up the spinnerPipeLength spinner 
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterPipeLength = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.PipeLength, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterPipeLength.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerPipeLength.setAdapter(adapterPipeLength);

        // Listens for changes in the selected item in each spinner 
        spinnerTypeGas.setOnItemSelectedListener(new GASOnItemSelectedListener());
        spinnerSupplyPressure.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SupplyOnItemSelectedListener());
        spinnerPipeLength.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
    }  // end mainProgram

    public void SpinnerNatGas() {
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSupplyPressure = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.NaturalGas, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterSupplyPressure.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerSupplyPressure.setAdapter(adapterSupplyPressure);
        adapterSupplyPressure.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } // end SpinnerNatGAs ()

    public void SpinnerProGas () {
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSupplyPressure = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.PropaneGas, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterSupplyPressure.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerSupplyPressure.setAdapter(adapterSupplyPressure);
        adapterSupplyPressure.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } // end SpinnerProGAs ()

    public class GASOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // this prevents false firing of Toast messages 
            if (intSpinnerCountGas < NO_OF_EVENTS_GAS) {
                intSpinnerCountGas++;
            } // end if 
            else {                
                spinnerTypeGasInt = spinnerTypeGas.getSelectedItemPosition();
                if(spinnerTypeGasInt == 1) {
                    //populate spinnerSupplyPressure accordingly
                    SpinnerNatGas();
                } // end if
                else if(spinnerTypeGasInt == 2) {
                    //populate spinnerSupplyPressure accordingly
                    SpinnerProGas();
                } // end else if
                if (spinnerTypeGasInt != 0) {
                    spinnerSupplyPressure.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textViewSupplyPressure.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    spinnerSupplyPressure.setSelection(0);
                    spinnerPipeLength.setSelection(0);
                    supplyPressureVisible = true;
                } // end else if
                else {
                    spinnerSupplyPressure.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    textViewSupplyPressure.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    textViewSelectPipeLength.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    spinnerPipeLength.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    supplyPressureVisible = false;
                    pipeLengthVisible = false;
                }// end else
            }// end if for false Toast message at app launch
        } // end onItemSelected

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // nothing to do
        } // end onNothingSelected
    } // end class GASOnItemSelectedListener 

    public class SupplyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // this prevents false firing of Toast messages 
            if (intSpinnerCountSupply < NO_OF_EVENTS_SUPPLY) {
                intSpinnerCountSupply++;
            } // end if 
            else {                
                spinnerSupplyPressureInt = spinnerSupplyPressure.getSelectedItemPosition();
                if (spinnerSupplyPressureInt != 0) {
                    textViewSelectPipeLength.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    spinnerPipeLength.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pipeLengthVisible = true;
                    spinnerPipeLength.setSelection(0);
                } // end if
                else {
                    textViewSelectPipeLength.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    spinnerPipeLength.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    pipeLengthVisible = false;
                } // end else
            }// end if for false Toast message at app launch
        } // end onItemSelected

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // nothing to do
        } // end onNothingSelected
    } // end class SupplyOnItemSelectedListener

    public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            if (intSpinnerCountLength < NO_OF_EVENTS_LENGTH) {
                intSpinnerCountLength++;
            } // end if 
            else {
                // This also gives the Row to look in the database for the CFH
                baseTableRowNumber = 0;
                spinnerPipeLengthInt = spinnerPipeLength.getSelectedItemPosition();
                //spinnerPipeLengthText = spinnerPipeLength.getSelectedItem().toString();
                // calculates the base table row number and stores it in variable baseTableRowNumber
                if (spinnerTypeGasInt == 1) {// Natural Gas is selected
                    baseTableRowNumber = (spinnerSupplyPressureInt - 1) * 18;
                }
                else if (spinnerTypeGasInt == 2) { // Propane is selected
                    baseTableRowNumber = 198 + (spinnerSupplyPressureInt - 1) * 18;
                } // end else if
                showResults();
            } // end else for check if firing at inializing
        } // end onItemSelected

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // nothing to do
        } // end onNothingSelected 
    } // end class MyOnItemSelectedListener

    public void showResults () {
        if (CSSTPipeSizingActivity.cursorResult != null) { 
            finalRow = (baseTableRowNumber + spinnerPipeLengthInt);
            if (finalRow < 0) {
                finalRow = 0;
            }
            if (finalRow == 0) {
                textViewSize15.setText(String.valueOf("0"));
                textViewSize19.setText(String.valueOf("0"));
                textViewSize25.setText(String.valueOf("0"));
                textViewSize31.setText(String.valueOf("0"));
                textViewSize37.setText(String.valueOf("0"));
                textViewSize46.setText(String.valueOf("0"));
                textViewSize62.setText(String.valueOf("0"));                
            } // end if
            else {
                cursorResult.moveToPosition(finalRow);
                textViewSize15.setText(String.valueOf(cursorResult.getInt(1)));
                textViewSize19.setText(String.valueOf(cursorResult.getInt(2)));
                textViewSize25.setText(String.valueOf(cursorResult.getInt(3)));
                textViewSize31.setText(String.valueOf(cursorResult.getInt(4)));
                textViewSize37.setText(String.valueOf(cursorResult.getInt(5)));
                textViewSize46.setText(String.valueOf(cursorResult.getInt(6)));
                textViewSize62.setText(String.valueOf(cursorResult.getInt(7)));
            } // end else 
        } // end if
    } //end showResults
} // end class CSSTPipeSizingActivity
```

In the first three lines of the mainProgram() method I declare my three spinners and then begin to populate them.  when the user selects a choice from spinnerTypeGas then the next spinner (spinnerSupplyPressure) becomes visible. then when the user selects an item from that spinnerSupplyPressure the third spinner (spinnerPipeLenght) becomes visible.  Data is  then displayed that is retrieved from a database.  Each spinner gets its array list from the string.xml file